# I cannot find the start() method in the Timer class

Tags: java, timer

The purpose of this program is to get a number from another user, then to count down.

I have not finished the program yet, because the methods i need to use is not there.

I am trying to start my timer, but i can not find the method start() & any other methods.

Do i need to import a different class? -----> Timer;

```
 package timerprojz;

 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.util.Timer;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;
 import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

 public class TimeProjz extends JFrame {

    JLabel promptLabel, timerLabel;
    int counter;
    JTextField tf;
    JButton button;
    Timer timer;

public TimeProjz() {

    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 5, 5)); // 2 row 2 colum and spacing

    promptLabel = new JLabel("Enter seconds", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    add(promptLabel);

    tf = new JTextField(5);
    add(tf);

    button = new JButton("start timeing");
    add(button);

    timerLabel = new JLabel("watting...", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    add(timerLabel);

    Event e = new Event();
    button.addActionListener(e);

}

public class Event implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


        int count = (int) (Double.parseDouble(tf.getText()));

        timerLabel.setText("T ime left:" + count);

        TimeClass tc = new TimeClass(count);
        timer = new Timer(1000, tc);
        timer.start(); <-----------------can not find symbol


       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no start method for the Timer. You sholud use it like this:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * Simple demo that uses java.util.Timer to schedule a task 
 * to execute once 5 seconds have passed.
 */

public class Reminder {
    Timer timer;

    public Reminder(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.format("Time's up!%n");
            timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Reminder(5);
        System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
    }
}
```

You can write you logic in the run method.

Answer (score 2):

**Multiple issues:**

- You are using [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) in Swing! use [`java.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead which has the [**`start()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#start%28%29) function you require :).
- Aside from not having `start()` function `java.util.Timer` doesn't have this type of constructor: `new Timer(1000, tc)` where `java.swing.Timer` has:

  `Timer(int delay, ActionListener litener)`
- Your instance creation style of the `Timer` in `actionPerformed()` function is also wrong. Check [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) Tutorial and example.

**It is recommended** to use Swing timers rather than general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task automatically executes on the `event-dispatch thread`. However, you might use a general-purpose timer if you don't plan on touching the GUI from the timer, or need to perform lengthy processing.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use [`Java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Use [`Java.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead, or work with [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
```

this will sort out the problem
instesd of importing `import java.util.Timer;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Timer class, you should be calling schedule method like :

```
Timer time = new Timer();
time.schedule(task, time);
```